# How to redirect URL entry to a specific file with a query string?

Tags: .htaccess

For example I have a PHP file named **footer1.php**

I want to make a rewriterule for this specific file named - "**footer1.php**"

My normal url structure is- **http://localhost/seestatus_new/footer1.php?page=about&cat=history**

I want to change this as -  **http://localhost/seestatus_new/about/history**

Sample of my .htaccess file -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

#turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#rewrite rule for footer1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/footer1\.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-%]+)$ footer1.php?page=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Please help this one positively. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most straightforward way to do this would just be using a redirect. However, this is not always desirable and has a lot of extra files needed.

---

However, you can use `window.href` to get the current page address, and use regular expressions to actual get the extension.

Your code would probably have loading up footer1.php on every web page (at every location within the file tree, regardless of the actual url), and then using regular expressions to parse the url and get the address. You can then set the variables like `page` and `cat` from within the php code.

This is a workaround, but it works and would allow you to use the desired page adress in the url without having to change your data loading structure. Hope this helps!

---

***Edit*: Code**

the way to get the base url of the webapge the php is loaded on is

`$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Beware, however, because these are editable by the client. Regardless, this is the best way to get the url of the webpage the php code is loaded on.

Then you would use the `parse_url` method

`$url_array = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH)`

this will return the url path. So, for example,

https://website.com/path/to/file

would return an array with key "path" and value "path/to/file".

Then just take this and use `preg_match` to turn it into the two variables normally appear in the header and define them as inline variables in the php. You can then continue with the rest of the code with the variable values defined, without having them in the url.